# Apply CKEDITOR to all elements

Tags: ckeditor

I want to apply the ckeditor inline editing to all elements with a specific attribute.

The problem is that its only applying to the very first element with the attribute, and not the rest.

How can i apply the ckeditor inline text editing to all elements with a specific attribute?

```
 $(".edit-element").ckeditor();
```

PS: im using ckeditor on elements that have contenteditable="true" and not textareas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about converting it to use .each? You can then also check the amount of elements you are targeting very easily (see comment);

```
$(".edit-element").each(function() {
    // Log element with something like console.log(this);
    $(this).ckeditor();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this the first time and it didnt work. this time i noticed it was sending out this error

```
 Uncaught Error: The specified element mode is not supported on element: "a".
```

and so I enabled the editor to work on "a" tags and span by adding this

```
 CKEDITOR.dtd.$editable.span = 1
 CKEDITOR.dtd.$editable.a = 1
```